# Как в label выставить расстояние между текстом по высоте?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

Всем привет. Мне нужно в label сделать меньший отступ между текстом по высоте. Как это реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let titleParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
titleParagraphStyle.maximumLineHeight=10 //Menyaem
let attriString = NSAttributedString(string:"Be or not to be? What is the question! Be or not to be? What is the question! Be or not to be? What is the question!", attributes:
        [ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: titleParagraphStyle])
lbl.attributedText = attriString
lbl.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: ibb.co/mDQj85 а как сделать чтобы текст был в левом верхнем углу?

Comment: Влево: titleParagraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.left
top без сохранения размера:lbl1.sizeToFit()   С сохранением размера самый простой способ использовать UITextField textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: Если очень хочется UILabel - то в текст добавляем "\n\n\n", вычисление их количества можно посмотреть здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-to-top-within-a-uilabel?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Я использую Ваш пример у меня label. @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
lbl.text = "test"
lbl.sizeToFit()
}

Но он не срабатывает, когда я нажал второй раз на кнопку пропадает лишнее пространство , при первом клике только текст меняеться.

Comment: Я видел публикацию но не мог разобраться.

Comment: У меня с UIButton все получается с 1 раза. Ну я бы попробовала вставить ниже sizeToFit self.view.layoutSubviews(), если бы не получалось. Вариант с UITextField самый простой. Если хотите, присылайте код. Вот пример  https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9xSU/6Lbk3dmDQ

Comment: Сделал все как вы говорили, можете посмотреть сам проект? https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2uKHFTccFnWQkpibGRLNnJQVFE

Comment: Здесь у Label было явно выставлено constraints.height = 150 в storyboard, из-за этого высота не менялась.

Comment: А если мне нужно чтобы был constraints, если текст больше него изменить размер шрифта? Могу я с вами как то связаться?

Answer (score 2):

1. Выбираете:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Затем устанавливаете что необходимо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Либо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Результат:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо я так понял spacing  для увеличение если уменьшить использовать min height і max height ?

Comment: @ЮраПетров Height multiple поставьте меньше 1

Comment: После переключение в text Attributed мой шрифт не отображаеться,   по g видно.
https://ibb.co/cCLEQk

Comment: @ЮраПетров Вы правильно подключили шрифт?